# TypeError: data; found string, expecting tuple in Abaqus by Python Script

Tags: python-2.7, abaqus

I want to read the data extracted from the text file into Abaqus File for the simulation.
Here is my code:

```
import os                 
os.chdir(r"dir")       
for file in os.listdir("dir"):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):    
          print os.path.join(r"dir", file)     
          with open(file) as f:     
              lines = f.readlines()  
              for line in lines[:-1]:  
                  first, second = tuple(map(float, line.split()))  
                  print '(%g, %g),' % (first, second),  
              first, second = tuple(map(float, lines[-1].split()))  
              pp =  '(%g, %g)' % (first, second)  
              print pp  

mdb.models['Model-1'].TabularAmplitude(data=(pp), name='NewAmplitude', smooth=
SOLVER_DEFAULT, timeSpan=STEP)
```

The error which comes up is:

> "TypeError: data; found string, expecting tuple"

Can anyone help in solving the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should fix the issue:

```
import os                 
os.chdir(r"dir")

pp = []
for file in os.listdir("dir"):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):    
        print os.path.join(r"dir", file)     
        with open(file) as f:     
            for line in f:  
                pp.append(map(float, line.split()))
print pp.__repr__()[1:-1]

mdb.models['Model-1'].TabularAmplitude(data=pp, 
                                       name='NewAmplitude', 
                                       smooth=SOLVER_DEFAULT, 
                                       timeSpan=STEP)
```

Comment: Can you fix the issue based on the the modified code. I have modified the code in the question.

Comment: Hi Tonechas, I have 50 text files which are to be read and stored in pp every time in loops. How to solve the issue? It will read each file and store in pp. I have updated the code which needs to be fixed.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. My answer was correct.  If you have a different problem, ask a new question.

Comment: Okay I am putting a new question. Kindly help.

Comment: Undeleted the question